# Is there a way to disable a SQL Server trigger for just a particular scope of execution?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

In SQL Server 2005, is there a way for a trigger to find out what object is responsible for firing the trigger? I would like to use this to disable the trigger for one stored procedure.

Is there any other way to disable the trigger only for the current transaction? I could use the following code, but if I'm not mistaken, it would affect concurrent transactions as well - which would be a bad thing.

```
DISABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL } ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]

ENABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL } ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]
```

If possible, I would like to avoid the technique of having a "NoTrigger" field in my table and doing a `NoTrigger = null`, because I would like to keep the table as small as possible.

The reason I would like to avoid the trigger is because it contains logic that is important for manual updates to the table, but my stored procedure will take care of this logic. Because this will be a highly used procedure, I want it to be fast.

> Triggers impose additional overhead on the server because they initiate an implicit transaction. As soon as a trigger is executed, a new implicit transaction is started, and any data retrieval within a transaction will hold locks on affected tables.

From: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/1,289483,sid87_gci1170220,00.html#trigger

Comment: you can use **Exec** function to diable and enable triggers from a stored procedure.
Example:
` EXEC ('ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerName on dbo.TriggeredTable')`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I just saw this article recently highlighted on the SQL Server Central newsletter and it appears to offer a way which you may find useful using the Context_Info on the connection:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1591

---

EDIT by Terrapin:

The above link includes the following code:

```
USE AdventureWorks;  
GO  
-- creating the table in AdventureWorks database  
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Table1') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1  
GO  
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(ID INT)  
GO   
-- Creating a trigger  
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Test ON dbo.Table1 FOR INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE  
AS  
DECLARE @Cinfo VARBINARY(128)  
SELECT @Cinfo = Context_Info()  
IF @Cinfo = 0x55555  
RETURN  
PRINT 'Trigger Executed'  
-- Actual code goes here  
-- For simplicity, I did not include any code  
GO
```

If you want to prevent the trigger from being executed you can do the following:

```
SET Context_Info 0x55555 
INSERT dbo.Table1 VALUES(100)
```

Comment: I really wish there was a better way for session (?) variables/state: what if `Context_Info` is already used for other purposes? (e.g. implementing multi-tennancy.) :(

Comment: @pst Well you have 128 bytes of binary data, so it's possible to put a whole datastructure in there for different purposes and wrap it with access functions.

Comment: I'm down voting because context_info is not persisted over connections, whereas transactions are.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow I'm not following you.  Your comment is correct, but I'm not seeing why it's relevant for the OP's use case.  Admittedly, I don't like the whole idea of disabling the trigger at all (even with a context check), but I'm not sure what you are saying is wrong here.

Comment: The solution works for the simple case as described in the question body about a single session, but the question title actually refers to the general case of a transaction that could be persisted across sessions; that is what brought me to the page and this doesn't answer that question.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow The title is misleading, the OP wanted to run a stored proc which would take care of the logic and wanted the trigger disabled during the procedure.  Once multiple connections come into it, then the DTC may or may not be involved.  I'm not sure there is a better way to do it in that scenario except to go ahead and set the same context on all the participating connections which might want the same trigger bypassed.  The fundamental problem is just distinguishing connections which are and are not privileged in some way.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow It's certainly possible to have multiple connections in a transaction and set the context only on the one updating the table with the trigger.  Other operations in the same transaction updating other tables wouldn't need to have that context set.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow You're entitled to your downvote, I'm just trying to understand if there is something I am missing which needs to be changed in this answer w.r.t. selectively disabling triggers from firing based upon context.

Comment: My issue is that the score is so high that this looks like de facto answer to the question in the title. It took me 10 minutes to build a test app to determine that it wasn't (maybe that is my fault for not being so good at SQL Server). I wouldn't have down voted the answer if you had been clear that this answer does not actually have anything to do with transactions, but everything to do with sessions: context info is persisted between transactions in the same session.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow Thankfully, we're allowed to ask questions that have more context than the title allows. Do you answer all questions by reading the title and ignoring the actual meat of the question?

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow The answer resolved the problem the OP was having. That the answer doesn't resolve your question is irrelevant. That said, your votes (up or down) are yours to cast at your discretion, whether in the spirit of the SE network or otherwise.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow Shall we change the title to "Is there a way to disable a SQL Server trigger for just a particular scope of execution?"  This would handle everything.

Comment: That's better, thanks. As a programmer you know that SO is the primary source of information about pretty much everything programming related. When you see an accepted answer with lots of votes to a question you think it solves a general problem; i.e. that stated in the title. Actually the fact that your answer solved a specific problem, but not the general one is quite subtle. I wanted to bring attention to that. Anyway we got there in the end. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow Please post the general problem as a question, I'm still not sure what the general problem is.

Answer (score 7):

If your trigger is causing performance problems in your application, then the best approach is to remove all manual updates to the table, and require all updates to go through the insert/update stored procedures that contain the correct update logic. Then you may remove the trigger completely.

I suggest denying table update permissions if nothing else works.

This also solves the problem of duplicate code. Duplicating code in the update SP and in the trigger is a violation of good software engineering principles and will be a maintenance problem.

Comment: Strongly disagree. There are many ways that data could be changed and business rules must be enforced at the database level. If the trigger is performing poorly it sould be rewritten but never removed or disabled. You can create very bad data integrity problems with your approach.

Comment: The stored procedure already maintains data integrity, and access to the table can be limited so that any process wishing to update it must use the proc. If you are permitting access to the table in many ways, the trigger is just a symptom of the problem, not the solution to it.

Comment: if it is possible to do as Jeffrey suggests, that would be the best solution.

Comment: While I agree 100% with you for anything I build, others (like myself) are stuck wrestling with sloppy 3rd Party Applications and their backend Databases that are loaded with Triggers.  Every night we have jobs that update data, and it is too slow to do so with all their Triggers firing, or some Triggers cause the updated records to go back out through an interface - when it is unnecessary for the edits we make.

Answer (score 4):

ALTER TABLE tbl DISABLE TRIGGER trg

http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/aa-az_5.htm

I don't understand the meaning of your 1st paragraph though

Comment: My first paragraph - In my trigger, is there a function I can use to get the name of the stored proc that fired my trigger? Kind of like using `if (trigger_nestlevel(object_id('NameOfTrigger')) = 0)` to make sure the trigger doesn't call itself

Answer (score 2):

Since you indicate that the trigger contains logic to handle all updates, even manual updates, then that should be where the logic resides. The example you mention, wherein a stored procedure "will take care of this logic" implies duplicate code. Additionally, if you want to be sure that every UPDATE statement has this logic applied regardless of author, then the trigger is the place for it. What happens when someone authors a procedure but forgets to duplicate the logic yet again? What happens when it is time to modify the logic?

Answer (score 2):

I waffled a bit on this one. On the one hand I'm very anti-trigger mostly because it's one more place for me to look for code executing against my table, in addition to the reasons stated in the article linked in the question post.

On the other hand, if you have logic to enforce stable and immutable business rules or cross-table actions (like maintaining a history table) then it would be safer to get this into a trigger so procedure authors and programmers don't need to deal with it - it just works.

So, my recommendation is to put the necessary logic in your trigger rather than in this one proc which, will inevitably grow to several procs with the same exemption.

Comment: +1 for being anti-trigger. Immutable business rules are quite rare, change requests are common. People are tempted to add a new trigger for a new business rule and soon you end up in trigger hell with no idea in what order the triggers will fire.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a good idea but it seems to work for me.  Transaction should prevent inserts to the table from other processes while trigger is disabled.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TriggerTest') IS NOT NULL
 DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TriggerTest
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TriggerTest]
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION trnInsertTable1s
;
DISABLE TRIGGER trg_tblTable1_IU ON tblTable1
;
BEGIN -- Procedure Code
    PRINT '@@trancount'
    PRINT @@TRANCOUNT
    -- Do Stuff

END -- Procedure Code
;
ENABLE TRIGGER trg_tblTable1_IU ON tblTable1

IF @@ERROR <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
ELSE COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: That's an odd way of creating or updating an existing sproc (there's an unapproved edit to change it to a simple drop/create, and fixing your block-copy error in the DROP PROCEDURE). Is there any advantage to doing it this way? Thanks!

Comment: That is just used as an add/update.  If you drop the procedure you can be sure that "CREATE PROCEDURE" will work.  I have used this when storing stored procedures in source control.  Each .sql file is a script that drops, if exists, and then the current stored procedure.  It is not relevant to the answer.  If/Else could be used also but the stored procedure content would need to be duplicated.

Comment: Sure, I just noticed it because of the edit. Yes, we generally have "if procedure exists drop, create" - I just haven't seen "drop, create as 'select 1', update" before.

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I hadn't thought about it for a while.  That is boilerplate code.  It has the addition of create as select 1 and also adds execute rights to a standard account.  Then the following code does an alter and has the actual code.  Edit the boilerplate with the actual account and the beginning of each stored procedure is the same except for the name and they all have execute rights to the standard account.  Useful for some situations.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do not disable the trigger. You are correct that will disable for any concurrent transactions.

Why do you want to disable the trigger? What does it do?  WHy is the trigger casuing a problem? It is usually a bad idea to disable a tigger from a data integrity perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider rewriting the trigger to imporve performance if performance is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with some other answers.  Do not disable the trigger.

This is pure opinion, but I avoid triggers like the plague.  I have found very few cases where a trigger was used to enforce database rules.  There are obvious edge cases in my experience, and I have only my experience on which to make this statement.  I have typically seen triggers used to insert some relational data (which should be done from the business logic), for insert data into reporting table ie denormalizing the data (which can be done with a process outside the transaction), or for transforming the data in some way.

There are legitimate uses for triggers, but I think that in everyday business programming they are few and far between.  This may not help in your current problem, but you might consider removing the trigger altogether and accomplishing the work the trigger is doing in some other fashion.

Comment: "DDL statements do not run in the context of a transaction?" You can try out and see for yourslef that this is wrong. 
BTW, Red Gate's SQL Compare can generate deployment script which all runs as one transaction.

Comment: You are right.  I think my time in Oracle-land must have poisoned me.

Answer (score 0):

I just confronted the same problem and came up with the following solution, which works for me.

1. Create a permanent DB table that contains one record for each trigger that you want to disable (e.g. refTriggerManager); each row contains the trigger name (e.g. strTriggerName = 'myTrigger') and a bit flag (e.g. blnDisabled, default to 0).
2. At the beginning of the trigger body, look up strTriggerName = 'myTrigger' in refTriggerManager.  If blnDisabled = 1, then return without executing the rest of the trigger code, else continue the trigger code to completion.
3. In the stored proc in which you want to disable the trigger, do the following:

---

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE refTriggerManager SET blnDisabled = 1 WHERE strTriggerName = 'myTrigger'

/* UPDATE the table that owns 'myTrigger,' but which you want disabled.   Since refTriggerManager.blnDisabled = 1, 'myTrigger' returns without executing its code. */

UPDATE refTriggerManager SET blnDisabled= 0 WHERE triggerName = 'myTrigger'

/* Optional final UPDATE code that fires trigger. Since refTriggerManager.blnDisabled = 0, 'myTrigger' executes in full. */

COMMIT TRANSACTION

---

All of this takes place within a transaction, so it's isolated from the outside world and won't affect other UPDATEs on the target table.

Does anyone see any problem with this approach?

Bill

Comment: This looks broken for `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT`, and in standard `READ COMMITTED` it blocks every other DML transaction until finished, preventing the effective use of row-level locks.  Basically you've implemented a crippled version of the the accepted answer.  If this wasn't such an old question I'd probably give you -1 just for the awful Hungarian notation and absence of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use '***Exec***' function to diable and enable triggers from a stored procedure. Example:  `EXEC ('ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerName on dbo.TriggeredTable')`