# TSQL - Disabling Triggers in Transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I've search high and low, and I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer to my question. Which tends to boil down to how exactly a `TRANSACTION` works in SQL Server.

Basically, will this do what I think it does.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DISABLE [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]

/*.. Do Some Updates ..*/

ENABLE [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]

COMMIT TRAN
```

I want to be able to fix some data in a table, without running the update triggers 
I have on the table. This is for a web app, so I'd like to make sure that if an update is done on the table from the web app, while I'm doing my work, `[my_update_trigger]` will still fire for the web app.

Comment: There is existing post that might help you

[tsql way to disable a trigger in the scope of a transaction][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174600/t-sql-is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-trigger-in-the-scope-of-a-transaction

Answer (score 4):

The update stuff is ok - the disable enable etc.

```
DISABLE TRIGGER [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]

/*.. Do Some Updates ..*/

ENABLE TRIGGER [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]
```

Have a look at the msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx

On making it session specific though: I'd doubt if that would work - the disable/enabled are DDL rather than DML, ie they act on the database objects rather than the data. I wouldn't have thought this would be in the scope of a Transaction

Answer (score 4):

Semicolons work for me:

```
BEGIN TRAN

;DISABLE [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]

/*.. Do Some Updates ..*/

;ENABLE [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: I know this isn't necessarily apropos to the OP's question, but it happened to meet my needs, so thank you!

Comment: Yup, this was the same issue for me. I got "incorrect syntax near keyword 'trigger'" or "... near keyword 'enable'". Adding in semicolons before an after allowed the statements to execute.

Answer (score 3):

I did some tests and, apparently, your code does exactly what you want it to do. Here is my test protocol:

```
   -- Session 1 --                                   -- Session 2 --
1. BEGIN TRANSACTION
2. DISABLE TRIGGER [my_update_trigger] ON [my_table]
3.                                                   UPDATE my_table SET x = y   -- blocks
4. ROLLBACK
                                                     -- unblocks *and triggers the trigger*
```

In addition, `SELECT is_disabled FROM sys.triggers where name = 'my_update_trigger';` reveals that the trigger is disabled after step 2 and enabled after step 4.

Thus, my conclusion is:

- Yes, enabling/disabling triggers is "global" and not "per session" (as can be seen by querying `sys.triggers`), **but**
- SQL Server's locking mechanisms ensure that disabling a trigger in a transaction locks the table, so other sessions won't "miss" their trigger.

---

A word of caution: `DISABLE TRIGGER` won't trigger an [implicit transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This is important if you are using (classic) ADO, since `Connection.BeginTrans` *won't* start an explicit transaction but will rather `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTION ON`. You need to perform [one of the operations listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) before disabling the trigger, or the `DISABLE TRIGGER` statement will be *outside* the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to execute ENABLE TRIGGER Directly From Source :

we can't write :

```
Conn.Execute "ENABLE TRIGGER trigger_name ON table_name"
```

instead, we can write :

```
Conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER trigger_name"
```