# Is it possible to prevent a trigger from running in a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

According to several resources, such as [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274348),

> A query that is executed within the context of a trigger is automatically wrapped in a transaction. If there are any distributed queries in the trigger code, the transaction is promoted to a distributed transaction automatically.

Simple question - is there a way to prevent this behavior?  I'm looking for a way to explicitly prevent code in my trigger from running in the context of a transaction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174600/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-sql-server-trigger-for-just-a-particular-scope-of-ex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to do something asynchronous so that the calling transaction doesn't have to wait, you may consider [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), which is designed to do exactly that - go fire off some asynchronous task, and return control to the caller, regardless of transaction scope.

Another idea is to not have your trigger perform the work, but instead pop a work item onto a queue table, and have a background process running continuously to process the queue. This isn't necessarily easy to do if your work item operates on the set of data in `inserted`/`deleted` but without more context it certainly seems like a viable option.

I don't know of a way to prevent a trigger from being a part of the calling transaction - in fact that's kind of the whole point.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "autonomous transaction", and the simplest way to implement is by creating a linked server to point to the original database.

See [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) for a possible solution.