# TSQL: Trigger on Commit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, esb

We have a back office system that inserts invoice information into an SQL database via a [MSDTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator) stored procedure, the application inserts header, then the detail information.

I have set up a [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.80).aspx) trigger on the header table that fires when a record is inserted.

The problem I am having is that the trigger is firing before the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` meaning that the details information might not be populated, which is required by the process that is triggered. Also if the system fires a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` the trigger has already fired.

I understand that triggers can't be assigned to a `COMMIT`, but was wondering if any one had any other thoughts.

I stumbled across a suggested solution for oracle where you create a Materlised View that updates `ON COMMIT`, and tried to find the TSQL equivalent which is Indexed Views, but had no luck implementing it.

**To Summarise:**
Is it possible to trigger upon a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` *possibly using Indexed Views* ?

---

**[CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.80).aspx) Trigger Code**

Sends a JMS Message to a queue, to be processed by [Sonic ESB](http://www.progress.com/en/sonic/sonic-esb.html).

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlTrigger(Name = "InvoiceTrigger", Target = "Table", Event = "FOR INSERT")]
public static void InvoiceTrigger()
{
    //Declare Connection vairables
    string connectionURL, connectionDomain, connectionUser, connectionPassword, connectionQueue;
    //Constant
    connectionUser = "user";
    connectionPassword = "pass";
    connectionQueue = "Queue";
    //Local Environment
    connectionURL = "tcp://IP:2506";
    connectionDomain = "Domain1";

    //Create connection sonic domain
    SonicSend send = new SonicSend(connectionURL, connectionDomain, connectionUser, connectionPassword, connectionQueue);
    
    //Send Test message to pipe
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlTriggerContext triggContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
    SqlPipe pipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
    SqlDataReader reader;
    switch (triggContext.TriggerAction)
    {
        case TriggerAction.Insert:
            // Retrieve the connection that the trigger is using
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"context connection=true"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT LSH_LINKCODE, DOC_CODE, LSH_DOCNUM FROM INSERTED;", connection);
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    string xml;
                    char cr = (char)13;
                    int i = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        
                        xml = @"<Invoice action='insert'>";
                        xml += "<LinkCode>" + reader.GetString(0).ToString() + "</LinkCode>";
                        xml += "<DocumentCode>" + reader.GetString(1).ToString() + "</DocumentCode>";
                        xml += "<DocumentNumber>" + reader.GetString(2).ToString() + "</DocumentNumber>";
                        xml += @"</Invoice>";
                        i++;
                        send.testJMSsend(xml);
                        
                    }
                   
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you take the code in the trigger and place it inside your transaction instead?

Comment: In that case, you'll need to rethink your code. You will need to have all the information (possibly in a holding table) before you fire insert/update that causes the trigger. You've published no code so very hard to help. And the rollback will also rollback any changes made by the trigger during the transaction.

Comment: Triggers are *triggered* by an operation - an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`. So no - you cannot "assign" a trigger to a `COMMIT` - you need to assign it to one of those operations (or combinations thereof)

Comment: Added CLR code, the problem with the rollback is that C# has already executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After helpful comments stating that utilizing the commit in a trigger wasn't possible.

I reviewed the ESB process that was kicked off by trigger, the process now queries the data with the passed information, this has fixed my problem due to the fact that the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` creates a lock on the data the query doesn't return results until there has been `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, thus meaning the process won't continue until the query returns data, so the Invoice details will always be populated.

Also if there was a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`, the process would time out throwing an error as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See this article, you'll probably have to use context_info and then fire the trigger afterwards for those records...

[Is there a way to disable a SQL Server trigger for just a particular scope of execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174600/t-sql-is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-trigger-in-the-scope-of-a-transaction)