# T-SQL trigger before commit to show a warning on certain table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Wanted to show a warning before doing an insert or update to some sensitive table. Looked at this questions([TSQL: Trigger on Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860816/tsql-trigger-on-commit)), but I wanted to implement something very similar to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Sales.bonus_reminder  
ON Sales.SalesPersonQuotaHistory  
WITH ENCRYPTION  
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS 
     RAISERROR ('Notify Compensation', 16, 10);  
GO
```

Comment: Do you want the transaction to then complete? Or fail/rollback?

Comment: Yes, I just want to warn the user about the sensitivity of the transaction.

Comment: That approach might not work as written, because doing a `raiserror` with error severity 16 will actually throw a potentially batch-ending error. You may want to consider either raising a severity 10 error (which is just a warning message). or print/select out the message you want the user to see. Also, make sure you handle any transactions which might be open as well.

Comment: But what if the user wants to rollback after seeing the warning? A user should decide whether to commit or rollback. That's why I wanted to show the warning before commit.

Comment: That can't be done directly in SQL. The only way you could do it is have the original proc that causes this trigger to be raised to pass along a message to the trigger via `CONTEXT_INFO()`. While it's more complicated, it would essentially be like having a parameter which says "are you sure you want to do this?" and unless passed, it will roll back. But there's no way to, strictly within SQL, do something like pop up a yes/no message box. HOwever your warning message could contain info on how to bypass the rollback.