# How can you `UPDATE` an SQL Server table without triggering the UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have an update trigger that updates some important status fields in a table `tblCurrent`.
When I first upload the daily batch of records into `tblCurrent` (circa 10K records), I perform some UPDATEs via three separate stored procedures when these are first uploaded and only then.
How can I prevent the update trigger from running during these three initial UPDATEs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable a SQL Server trigger for just a particular scope of execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174600/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-sql-server-trigger-for-just-a-particular-scope-of-ex)

Comment: A nasty hack would be create another table which is grouped to your other tables. This new table has 1 column, called locked. It's either true or false. Before your stored procedure, set it to false. After set it to true. Of course, this does mean that all your queries have to manually check on the condition but this is how we do it. It's an ugly hack and prone to human error, but it does work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could temporary disable triggers for the table and then enable them back. [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

DISABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]

ENABLE TRIGGER { [ schema_name . ] trigger_name [ ,...n ] | ALL }
ON { object_name | DATABASE | ALL SERVER } [ ; ]

For example to disable all triggers for given table run following statement:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON tblCurrent;
```

Comment: But this would affect other concurrent connections.  Not a good idea.  The following article has some alternatives: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1591/disabling-a-trigger-for-a-specific-sql-statement-or-session/

Comment: This is perfect.  The three Stored Procedures that I run once a day after a new batch of records to tblCurrent usually take upto twenty minutes total with the triggers enabled.  It now takes under five minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this would be to have some data in `tblCurrent` that enables you to detect the situation you describe as "first uploaded".  For example, a BIT column "FirstUploaded", or a column that is NULL when first uploaded, or even a BIT column "DontFireTrigger".

Then write your trigger to detect this condition, and conditionally update the status fields.

Admittedly this looks like a nasty hack, but perhaps no worse than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use session variable Context_Info. Before the update set context_info to some value and then test it inside the trigger

`-- update code 
SET Context_Info 0x55555
Update Table set ...`

-- Code Inside the trigger
SELECT @Cinfo = Context_Info()
IF @Cinfo <> 0x55555 BEGIN
...
END

Comment: Session variable will be global between multiple functions, triggers etc. If somebody will try such method multiple times, Context_Info will be mixed. It may lead to errors. Better way is to create temp table and check if it exist (via system catalog) - you can use unique name for such table every time.