# How do you prevent two triggers on separate tables from both firing at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have one table called ClientInfo that stores a client's personal information and another table called EmergencyContactInfo that stores their emergency contact information. Right now I have an update trigger on my ClientInfo table that inserts a single record into a third table called ClientLog if any of their personal information changes. I would also like to create a ClientLog record if the client's emergency contact information changes.

The problem is that the user can change both a client's personal information and their emergency contact information with a single save from my webpage. If I put an update trigger on my EmergencyContact table, then both my triggers will fire and the ClientLog table will insert two new records when I only want one.

From what I understand there is no such thing as an update trigger that spans across multiple tables. What is an alternative approach I could take that would insert a single record when both the client's personal information AND their emergency contact information changes?

Comment: Cold you just move the auditing to the procedure that does the update instead of using a trigger?

Comment: "If I put an update trigger on my EmergencyContact table, then both my triggers will fire and the ClientLog table will insert two new records when I only want one."

Why would you want that? It seems *completely* reasonable to me to write two records. What are you writing into ClientLog?

Comment: Possible option using Context_Info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174600/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-sql-server-trigger-for-just-a-particular-scope-of-ex

Comment: I would say if you can't put the auditing logic in the code, make the thing that looks at the audit data understand the 2 records are from 1 event.  Some sort of correlation id - but again this will come from the code.  Occasionally suppressing 1 trigger will cause more problems down the line.

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately not because there are several other automated processes that go on that can change a clients information and it would be a total mess to maintain.

Comment: @aquinas In my question I said it was a log table for simplicity, but the table is actually used to send soap requests to another service. Each unnecessary record in the table will send an unnecessary request.

Comment: Can you write out your *actual* problem? This sounds like an X/Y problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

For example, it sounds like what you might ACTUALLY be trying to do is send another service information that a person record was updated. Well, in that case, just create a merge statement that inserts into your table if there isn't already an existing record. But, again, I'm guessing here. But I think you're asking the wrong question. :)

Comment: The easiest, best way is to just not use triggers at all for this. You should, if you want to log these changes, do it in your server-side code OR call a stored procedure that looks for changes between what you send it and what is in the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct that a trigger cannot span multiple tables.

There is also no such thing as preventing a trigger from firing.

What you CAN do is include logic in your trigger that prevents it from doing anything if certain conditions are true.

Now I don't know what you're writing to your log table, and what logic you would want to enforce, but an example would be, when the trigger fires, if there is already a log entry (row in the Log Table) for the same Client in the past x hours, then simply don't insert a new row in the log table.

You can even handle multiple row insert/updates with an `OUTER JOIN` to the log table, or a `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` clause.

But basically what I'm saying is, let both triggers fire, and in both triggers, check to see if some condition is true/false before writing to the Log Table.   Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: What about 'DISABLE TRIGGER`? I don't comprehend the real question here either but isn't that one statement untrue?

Comment: I don't think "DISABLE TRIGGER" is what the OP had in mind when he said "Prevent a trigger from firing".   The first is universal, the second, as I read it, is conditional.

Comment: As I read the question I realized it wasn't really a solution to OP's problem. I see your point although I'm not sure everyone will read it that way.

Comment: To be sure, the question could be worded a little more clearly.

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry I'm not great at wording things. Which part is causing confusion and I'll edit my question to try to make it better

Comment: @TabAlleman Also I'm marking yours as the accepted answer because your suggestion to let both triggers fire and then only conditionally inserting a log record should work for me. When either of the triggers fire, I'm going to check if the most recent log is for the same client and if so, don't insert another record if the last one was less than 200 milliseconds ago. That should work just fine, thanks.

Comment: @JaimieKnox well your very last sentence in your question asks how to insert a row if A OR B.   But your current situation does that already.  You're really trying to ask how to insert only a single row if A AND B.   Kudos for wanting to be clear!   : )

Comment: @JaimieKnox your 200ms condition seems rather arbitrary. If you wrap the update of both tables in a transaction, you can potentially store the connection and transaction IDs with your data to make a reliable logic check. Create your own ID per transaction or mess with `select c.connection_id, t.transaction_id
from sys.dm_exec_connections c
 cross join sys.dm_tran_current_transaction t
where c.session_id = @@spid`

Comment: IMO, you're making a simple operation unnecessarily complex. What you're doing isn't a new thing, it's been done literally for decades. You need a valid database schema with correct primary and foreign keys, and need to let the triggers run as designed. It's irrelevant if the record in the log table is xxx seconds old. It's only relevant if it represents a change. If not, it shouldn't be there. This is one of those times when you get a chance to fix a problem in the design stage instead of needing an eternal sack of workarounds and patches after it goes into production.

Comment: @PushfPopf your comment should probably be a comment on the Question, rather than on this answer.   It seems to be addressed toward the OP.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't see a place for that. I'm sure it will be ignored anyway so no loss.

Comment: @PushfPopf Well I appreciate comments but try not to make assumptions. It would be great if I had the resources to create a normalized database, but sometimes the preferred method doesn't make business sense and the best you can do is to apply bandaids to what you already have. I'm reading into Tim's suggestion now to create a more reliable logic check.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this unnecessarily difficult and error prone.

If each data table has a separate log table and it's own trigger, you can ignore the entire issue and just let them work as they're supposed to.

If you want to view the log info together, you can use a JOIN on the two tables when you display the data.

Comment: While I agree with letting these triggers run free and then using a join (probably in a view), you aren't addressing non-trivial technical challenge of what that join condition might be.

Comment: I assumed that the tables would have appropriate pk/fk. If not, they would need to be fixed.

Comment: I'm saying it probably goes beyond that to figure out which rows in the log tables should be "connected" to represent one update to avoid false duplicates.

Comment: The records are clients and client contacts. It's only necessary to join on the clientid, then order by the timestamp, I'm really not seeing anything overly complex here. If the OP wants to do a little extra work, he could add an UpdateID to both log tables, since they're all from a single form submission anyway.